# multi submit button in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following this tutorial to build a form with multiple submit buttons:
 http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/cM1X161112-Handling-multiple-submit-buttons-on-the-same-form---MVC-Razor.html

but it didn't work...
I have 2 buttons: **"Login"**, **"Send"**

I want my "Send" button to send the password to the user by email. (In the table "`aspnetuser`" I have the attribute "`Email`").

How can i do this?

Comment: Can you post the code in which you attempted to implement the technique in your link?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Please post the View and Controller codes and if possible the view model too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to do two things, let a user login or retrieve their password. Best practice would be to split these into two separate forms.

Your first form would be for people logging in and would post username/password to a Login action on your Members controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Members"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.Label("username")
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.Label("password")
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
}
```

Your second form would be for people who forgot their password and would post username to a ForgotPassword action on your Members controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Members"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.Label("username")
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />
    </div>
}
```

As a side note, you shouldn't send users their password in plain text. Instead you should allow them to reset their password. There's a much better explanation of why and how here:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/admin/recovering-and-changing-passwords-cs

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @timothyclifford, you are trying to do two things in one form. There are situations where it's preferential to do this, but for 99% of scenarios a link to a second form is the way to go.

A while ago I did implement an action invoker which simulates the functionality you are looking for. It allows you to specify which action you are directing to within the form values.

It allows you to mark controller actions with an attribute that helps with the selection process.

I have just uploaded a working sample to github: https://github.com/xenolightning/asp-mvc-formaction

**FormActionInvoker.cs**

```
/// <summary>
///     Searches the controller for the correct action. Prioritizes FormAction attributed Actions first.
///     Then searches via Method Code
/// </summary>
public class FormActionActionInvoker : AsyncControllerActionInvoker
{
    protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
    {
        foreach (var mi in controllerDescriptor.ControllerType.GetMethods())
        {
            //Searches for the form action attribute first. And if it is present, then it looks
            //checks to see if the request is valid. This hpens BEFORE it checks the action name
            //which now means ActionName becomes obsolete
            var fa =
                mi.GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(x => x is FormActionAttribute) as FormActionAttribute;

            if (fa == null)
                continue;

            if (FormActionAttribute.GetAction(controllerContext) != null &&
                fa.IsValidForRequest(controllerContext, mi))
                return new ReflectedActionDescriptor(mi, actionName, controllerDescriptor);
        }

        ActionDescriptor ad = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);
        var rad = ad as ReflectedActionDescriptor;

        if (rad == null)
            return ad;

        //Here we have to check that the form action attibute isn't in required mode. If it is
        //and the form-action is null then we should return null
        var formA =
            rad.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(x => x is FormActionAttribute) as
                FormActionAttribute;

        if (formA != null && FormActionAttribute.GetAction(controllerContext) == null &&
            formA.Mode == FormActionMode.Required)
            return null;

        return rad;
    }
}
```

**FormActionAttribute.cs**

```
/// <summary>
///     When Required the action cannot be invoked unless the form has
///     the required form-action value
/// </summary>
public enum FormActionMode
{
    Required,
    Normal
}

public class FormActionAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public const string HTTP_FORM_NAME = "form-action"; 

    public FormActionAttribute(params string[] values)
        : this(FormActionMode.Required, values)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor to specify the FormActionMode
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mode">
    ///     Specify Normal to allow invocation of the action with out the matching form action. Defaults to
    ///     Required
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="values"></param>
    public FormActionAttribute(FormActionMode mode, params string[] values)
    {
        Values = values;
        Mode = mode;
    }


    public string[] Values
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public FormActionMode Mode
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        string action = GetAction(controllerContext);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
            return true;

        return Values.Any(x => x.Equals(action, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) ||
               methodInfo.Name.Equals(action, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns the form action from the current context. Returns null if there is no action
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext"></param>
    /// <returns>Null if there is no action</returns>
    internal static string GetAction(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        string action = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Params[HTTP_FORM_NAME];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
            return null;

        //Stops errors on multiple value submissions
        //this will choose the first value in the form
        if (action.IndexOf(",") > -1)
            return action.Split(',')[0];

        return action;
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    protected override IActionInvoker CreateActionInvoker()
    {
        return new FormActionActionInvoker();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [FormAction]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        return View("Login", model);
    }

    [FormAction("Forgot")]
    public ActionResult DoesntMatterWhatThisIs(LoginModel model)
    {
        return View("Forgot", model);
    }

    [FormAction(FormActionMode.Normal)]
    public ActionResult Three(LoginModel model)
    {
        return View("Three", model);
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<h2>A Multi Action Form:</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="@Html.IdFor(x => x.Username)" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="@Html.IdFor(x => x.Password)" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="form-action" value="Login">Login</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="form-action" value="Forgot">Forgot Password</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="form-action" value="Three">Do Three</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```